# Firebase - Query Chains

Tags: angularjs, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I have an interesting issue here. Our software includes a feature that allows dynamic commission assignments based on hierarchy between sales reps, managers and however many layers our users want to support in their usage of our software. A user may look like this:

```
$uid
    fname
    lname
    lineage
         fatherlink
               $uid_of_another_user
         childlink
               $uid_of_another_user
               $uid_of_another_user
```

Okay so now lets say that each of the children in the `childlink` object contain two more children. I want to be able to start at a manager for example, and create an array of all his children, and his children's children etc... Since we support as many management levels as you want, the querying for all the children under a given user needs to be dynamic. Here's what we have now.

```
var children = [];
        _.child('user/' + $localStorage.currentUser.uid + '/lineage/child_link').on('value', function(sn1) {
            sn1.forEach(function(sn2) {
                _.child('user/' + sn2.key + '/lineage/child_link/').on('value', function(sn3) {
                    sn3.forEach(function(sn4) {
                        _.child('user/' + sn4.key + '/lineage/child_link/').on('value', function(sn5) {
                            sn5.forEach(function(sn6) {
                                _.child('user/' + sn6.key + '/lineage/child_link/').on('value', function(sn7) {
                                    sn7.forEach(function(sn8) {
                                        _.child('user/' + sn8.key + '/lineage/child_link/').on('value', function(sn9) {
                                            sn9.forEach(function(sn11) {
                                                _.child('user/' + sn11.key + '/lineage/child_link/').on('value', function(sn12) {
                                                    sn12.forEach(function(sn13) {
                                                        children.push(sn13.key)
                                                    })
                                                });
                                                children.push(sn11.key)
                                            })
                                        });
                                        children.push(sn8.key)
                                    })
                                });
                                children.push(sn6.key)
                            })
                        });
                        children.push(sn4.key)
                    })
                });
                children.push(sn2.key)
            })
        });
        return children;
```

Obviously, the catch is that this only queries 6 layers deep. Any ideas? Even possible?

Comment: Whether it is possible is a matter of trying it and seeing whether it works. Whether this code is sensible/feasible, well... you already seem to know, else you wouldn't be here. So what's your real question? Is it how to do this recursively? Are you concerned about the performance? And if so, did you try it already? What were the results vs what you expected?

Comment: AngularJS programmers avoid the [Pyramid of Doom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_of_doom_(programming)) (AKA [Callback Hell](http://callbackhell.com/)) by [chaining promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises). Convert the asynchronous callback-based operations to promises and **chain** them.

Comment: Perfect that was what I needed. Not sure why I didn't think of that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @georgeawq this was our solution:

```
    children: function(callback) {
        function getChildren(a) {
            _.child("user/" + a + "/lineage/child_link/").once("value", function(a) {
                null != a.val() ? a.forEach(function(a) {
                    children.push(a.key), getChildren(a.key)
                }) : children.sort(); callback(children)
            })
        }
        var children = [];
        getChildren($localStorage.currentUser.uid);
    },
```

Basic but a perfect solution. Thank you!